# SQL SELECT data from TABLE where NUMBER EXISTS in another TABLE in date range

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, exists

I have two tables.  I want to select all from **TABLE1** where **ID** exists in **TABLE2** and has a **DATE** of any day in the current calendar year.

**TABLE 1**

[image]

**TABLE 2**

[image]

**DESIRED RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Show what you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WHERE EXISTS` like

```
select * from table1 t
where exists (select 1 from table2
where ID = t.ID and year([DATE]) = year(getdate());
```

As @GarethD pointed to have the `WHERE` modified without use if `YEAR()` function which will use the index (if any on that column)

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2
WHERE ID = t.ID 
AND [Date] >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) 
AND [Date] <  DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0));
```

Comment: As a side point, although more verbose I would be inclined to use `AND [Date] >= DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AND [Date] < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)` as the predicate for filtering the year rather than `YEAR([Date]) = YEAR(GETDATE())`. It will prevent any function calls on the data, and make the predicate sargable. I have upvoted nonetheless, as it clearly demonstrates the correct solution.

Comment: @GarethD, Yes, understood that your sole point of saying is *use of index in where* ...  make sense totally.

Comment: This gave me exactly what I needed.  I was hitting a brick wall with the searched I was executing on here and not getting the data to come back correctly.  Thank you to you all and sorry for any annoyance in repetition.

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 
(
ID int
,NAME varchar(50)
,Description varchar(250)
)
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID,NAME,Description)
VALUES (1,'One','The First Item'),
(2,'Two','The second item'),
(3,'Three','The third item'),
(4,'Four','The fourth item'),
(5,'Five','The fith item'),
(6,'Six','The sixth item'),
(7,'Seven','The seventh item'),
(8,'Eight','The eight item'),
(9,'Nine','The ninth item');

CREATE TABLE #Table2
(
ID int
,Date date
)
INSERT INTO #Table2 (ID,Date)
VALUES (1,'1/15/2015'),
(1,'8/8/2015'),
(2,'9/23/2014'),
(3,'7/19/2015'),
(4,'4/23/2010'),
(4,'6/30/2009'),
(4,'12/25/2014'),
(5,'5/17/2015'),
(6,'12/3/2008'),
(9,'9/25/2009'),
(9,'2/2/2015'),
(9,'1/31/2012')
;


SELECT
*
FROM #Table1 t
WHERE t.ID IN (SELECT t2.ID FROM #Table2 t2 WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,t2.Date) = DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()))

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
```